# vba hide some rows, freeze some rows when scrolling down

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide, vertical-scrolling

I have action buttons at the top of the sheet that will return data in rows 26 and down if the user clicks on one of the action buttons. When the user scrolls down on the sheet, I want rows 5 to 24 to become hidden and the remainder of the rows from 1 to 26 frozen/visible. It appears that Excel doesn't reconize when I scroll down. Maybe an alternative can be to activate a copy of the sheet with no contents that I would originally hide. So this alternative sheet will be activated the moment the user scrolls past row 26

[image]

So when the rows are hidden, I want this while the column headers remain visible:

[image]

I have tried some code but none of it works.
Attempt 1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim visibleRange As Range
    Set visibleRange = ActiveWindow.visibleRange.Rows(1).Resize(VisibleRowsCount)

    If Not Intersect(Target, visibleRange) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.row > 26 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
            Rows("5:24").Hidden = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
            Rows("5:24").Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Function VisibleRowsCount() As Long
    VisibleRowsCount = ActiveWindow.visibleRange.Rows.Count
End Function
```

Attempt 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_WindowScroll(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Target.Cells(1, 1).row > 26 Then
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
        Rows("5:24").Hidden = True
    Else
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
        Rows("5:24").Hidden = False
    End If
    Debug.Print Target.Cells(1, 1).row
End Sub
```

Attempt 3:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Scroll(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Target.Cells(1, 1).row > 26 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
            sO.Rows("5:24").Hidden = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
            sO.Rows("5:24").Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Attempt 4:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_WindowScroll(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Cells(1, 1).row > 26 Then
        If Not frozenPanes Then
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
            frozenPanes = True
        End If
        Rows("5:24").Hidden = True
    Else
        If frozenPanes Then
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
            frozenPanes = False
        End If
        Rows("5:24").Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Please help. Really I have no idea how to activate the scrolling, hide rows, and freeze some panes.

Comment: The ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True command freezes the pane based on the location of the active cell.  If the active cell is in row 135, that's where the panes will get frozen.  Select the row (looks like row 5) where you want the frozen rows to be before you set the FreezePanes.

Comment: True. But  I need the column headers to show also  and as mentioned above, it is scrolling that does not get activated when I scroll and

Comment: It's not scrolling because you locked the panes at a row that's off the displayed portion of the screen.  If you want to include the column headings (sorry, I missed that part) then select row 27 prior to freezing the panes.  Do a quick test on a test workbook:  Scroll down to row 100 and Freeze Panes.  You won't be able to scroll afterwards becuase the frozen portion of the sheet takes up the entire displayed portion.  Since it's frozen, you can't scroll (which is what defines frozen).

Comment: Yes but then rows 1 to 4 are not visible. The idea behind mentioning scrolling is that I want to unhide rows 5 to 24 when the user scrolls back up.  I understand though what you mean by active cell. Thanks for that

Comment: Hide rows 5-24, select row 27, then freeze panes.  On the scroll event, unhide the rows.

Comment: Frank. that's exactly what I tried to do as you can see in my code above. The scrolling did not trigger the event. What is more, when I do hide the rows, the action buttons and drop-down list remain visible. Maybe, the one thing I mentioned is probably the answer to this. To activate another sheet showing only the display in the second image?

Comment: You need to select row 27 prior to freezing panes.

Answer (score 0):

So I've added another action button that takes the user to a different sheet to review the data and return to the sign-off page. That resolves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and unhide rows, I can see that in your code but in my Excel there are no "Scroll" or "WindowScroll" events for the Worksheet object.
There is no need to move to another sheet when you hide the rows and the buttons with an extra button that stays visible.
You hide buttons this way:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Visible = False
```

Comment: I voted you up again. I think it is a bit lame to vote someone down without an explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I agree. And thank you for your consideration. My actual question was not answered and so I found another way to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for ages, it seems hidden rows were completely messing with the code